# gem server using rvm

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Hopefully an easy one - started using rvm and one of the benefits it gives aside from easily switching between gemsets and ruby versions is that I no longer need to install new gems under root (So, no need for sudo). Back when I used to do that, the way i got to my gem docs was by running;

```
gem server
```

which gave me a home-hosted site so i could browse the documentation. Now, when I install a gem I don't need to do it under root,

```
#so it's just
gem install hpricot
```

but when I then run gem server, it only lists those gems I've installed under root. So what I'm finding myself doing is;

```
gem install hpricot #to get the gem under rvm
sudo gem install hrpicot  #so i can still use gem server
```

Am I missing something or is this just how it is? I work a lot offline so really need those local docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `gem server` under a particular ruby/gemset works well for me. Check `rvm info` to make sure your shell vars are pointing to the correct ruby/gemset. Also, which version of rvm are you running? I've ran `rvm get head` a few weeks ago and the version it's showing for me is `rvm 1.9.2`.